# Sending mail in iphone 5 using MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, email, mfmailcomposer

I am developing an app in which i have to send email using MFMailComposeViewController to multiple user selecting from contact list.When I send email once it goes but when i do it second time I get following warning: Attempt to present  on  while a presentation is in progress!.Please let me know whats the issue here.

Thanks.

Comment: i am sure with a quick search for this error message (which is quite self-explanatory) you can find a solution here.

Comment: Update the question with your code and the complete line of warning you get.

Answer (score 1):

A kind of communication issue between parent-child .That means you are trying to present `MFMailComposeViewController`, without dismissing the previous.
Well, I can't explain further without looking at your code.

Comment: -(void)mail_inquiry
{
      MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
       if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
        
    {
          picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
          [picker setSubject:@"Muv Muv Game invitation"];
         NSString *emailBody;
            emailBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@""];
[picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];
        
        [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
        
        [picker release];
    }
    

}

Comment: Why don't you add this in your question?? Add this there, will help

Comment: -(void)mail_inquiry { MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init]; if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) { picker.mailComposeDelegate = self; [picker setSubject:@"Muv Muv Game invitation"]; NSString *emailBody; emailBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@""]; [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES]; [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES]; [picker release]; } } –

Comment: AND I am getting following issue: <MFMailComposeViewController: 0x1431bad0> on <UINavigationController: 0x9d47e50> while a presentation is in progress!

Comment: @user1626842 Your comments should be added to the question not here. -1 to the question as this is information that is need to help and you have failed to include it.